# Python: parent class is still an undefine variable after import

Tags: python

I am implementing a graph and I made a Route class a subclass of an Edge class. I attempted to add a "distance" feature in my Route class, so the constructor of my Route class overrides the constructor of my Edge class.

Since they are in different modules, I used "from Edge import *" in my Route class; however, the program (PyDev) still throws the error, Undefined variable: Edge

Here's my implementation:

```
'''
An (directed) edge holds the label of the node where the arrow is coming from
and the label of the node where the arrow is going to
'''

class Edge:

    '''
    Constructor of the Edge class
    '''
    def __init__(self, fromLabel, toLabel):
        self.__fromLabel = fromLabel
        self.__toLabel = toLabel

    '''
    Get the label of the node where the arrow is coming from
    @return the label of the node where the arrow is coming from
    '''
    def getFromLabel(self):
        return self.__fromLabel

    '''
    Get the label of the node where the arrow is going to
    @return the label of the node where the arrow is going to
    '''
    def getToLabel(self):
        return self.__toLabel
```

---

```
from Edge import *

'''
A Route is inherited from the Edge class and is an edge specialized for the 
CSAirGraph class
'''

class Route(Edge):

    '''
    Constructor of the Route class
    '''
    def __init__(self, fromLabel, toLabel, distance):
        Edge.__init__(self, fromLabel, toLabel)
        self.__distance = distance

    '''
    Get the distance between two adjacent cities
    @return: the distance between two adjacent cities
    '''
    def getDistance(self):
        return self.__distance
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an `Edge.py` somewhere? Note that module/package names are all lowercase *usually*.

Comment: I wrote the Edge class and there is the "Edge.py" module in my src folder.

On a side note: you said I should use lower case for my module?

Comment: like class Edge ---> class edge
and class Route(Edge) ---> class route(edge) ?

Comment: no, like module name -> "edge". Read PEP8.

Comment: I see. Let me fix the naming of my modules first.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure that I have the module though. The same error is thrown on my Route(Edge), AirlineGraph(Graph), and City(Node) class. I think something else causes the problem.

Comment: This might be an error introduced while copying, but the Edge code you posted doesn't have a closing `'''`.  Could you edit your post to include the entire text of `Edge.py`?

Comment: I'll do it right now. ;)

Comment: Your code works just fine for me as ordinary Python scripts (I don't use PyDev so I'm not a familiar with its error messages -- "Undefined variable" isn't a Python error message -- or with whether it's getting confused about the Edge/Edge doubling.)  If it's not a PyDev quirk, the only thing I can think is that the Edge you're importing from isn't the one you think it is.  You could comment out everything in the second script, and instead of `from Edge import *`, try `import Edge` and then `print Edge` `print dir(Edge)` to rule out problems there.

Comment: @Sean: did you change the module name and confirm that the new module contains what you think it does?

Comment: I wrote both of the class by myself and they are created in the same src folder.

Comment: I suspect that the errors are PyDev specific.